# How to find informix datasource in visual studio to connect to

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6, informix

I want to use `EF6` with `Informix` database .

I have searched a lot and find that i can get

[EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 6.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.IBM.DB2/)  from NuGet for Both `Informix` and `DB2` but my main problem is the **connection**

How to create a connection to my `informix` database i can't find any provider for .net to use ?

- > I want to get a window like this :

  :[image]

> My current window :

[image]

---

> Notes:

- I use the informix server version : IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version
    12.10.FC3
- I use the informix client SDK version : 3.50
- I use Visual studio 2012
- .net framework 4.5

---

**EDIT** :according to the recommendations:
I run `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

and configure my `ODBC` but still unable to access the `informix DB` through V.S :

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**EDIT2:**
According to the recommendation i have installed `IBM Informix Software Bundle` and able to connect to visual studio through `View -->Server Explorer` and find all the tables .but still can't find the informix odbc when i try to change the data source through Entity framework like this :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0903linqentity/

Comment: You need the following software to complete the example:
IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC, CLI, and .NET (version 9.5.3 or later)
IBM Database Add-ins for Visual Studio (version 9.5.3 or later)
Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1
.NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217

Comment: I read all these articles and try to download the `IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio` but the button `I confirm` doesnot do any action !!

Comment: its bug on them , you need to get Data provider to make this run

Comment: @Eldho: i need direct link to the `IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio`

Comment: @just_name: any success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 5:** In order to get the exact same screens you're looking for and to be fully integrated with Visual Studio, with all the bells and whistles you're now demanding, you will need to install **IBM Data Server .NET Provider for Informix**, which does not have a **Developer Edition**. You can only get a **Trial Version**, which requires additional registration information besides that of a regular **Developer Registration**.

See detailed full information in the link below, including the exact same integration screens between **Visual Studio** and **IBM Informix** you're looking for: [Get started with the IBM Data Server .NET Provider for Informix](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/)

[image]

**EDIT 4:** Code snippet testing the ODBC connection:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connString = "Dsn=IFMX32;uid=informix";
            string cmd = "select * from syschfree";

            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);

            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd, conn);

            conn.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT 3:** I was able to establish an ODBC connection as explained before using the "bundle" package ***Informix Developer Edition for Windows 32 Version  12.10TC5DE*** which includes not only the client SDK but also a test server. As you can see in the picture below, i connected to the **sysmaster** database. Whether or not you need a test server, perhaps you should install this 32-bit bundle package because it may be installing some additional components that would enable you to get connected.

[image]

Here some more details on how the connection was configured in the ODBC Data Source Administration tool:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** The 32-bit Client SDK produces the very same results as shown before.

[image]

**EDIT 1:** You may want to give this a try:

Assuming your client SDK is properly installed, then you should be able to see your driver as shown below. In my case, version 4.10 Developer Edition (64-bit).

[image]

Then create a User Data Source as below, using your driver and DB information:

[image]

And finally, in Visual Studio, your newly created Data Source should be available:

[image]

I don't have a server i could use to test this any further, but again, you could give it a try.

Comment: Could you look to my question with the new edit please?

Comment: did you try the last step, which is to add the connection in VS? What error do you get? I noticed from your print screen that you're missing **Microsoft ODBC Data Source** option...

Comment: Please see **EDIT 3** in my post.

Comment: Could you provide a direct link to `Informix Developer Edition for Windows 32 Version 12.10TC5DE` ? should i uninstall any previous installations before this ?  
NOTE:My window is `64bit`

Comment: Unfortunately, a direct link is not possible because you have to be a registered user in order to download. But it shouldn't be a problem at all, just register. Anyway, the download page is this [IBM - DeveloperWorks - Informix](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/informix/index.html). My machine is 64 bit as well. Definitely i would uninstall all previously installed packages to start it clean and eliminate any potential issues. That's what i did.

Comment: Thanks, Could you provide me a link to `Informix Developer Edition for Windows 32 Version 12.10TC5DE` cuz i cann't find it in the download link you provide

Comment: Try this: https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=ifxids&S_CMP=web_dw_rt_swd

Comment: Please see **EDIT 4**.

Comment: I make `EDIT2`, could you look to the question please.

Comment: Creating an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** is a step up in the ladder... Are you even able to connect to the database at all? How can you create a data model if you can't connect to the database? In your list of data sources, where's **Microsoft ODBC Data Source** ?

Comment: i can connect easily to my informix database i go to `View --->Server Explorer--->Right click on Data Connections --->Add Connection --->Change the data source ---> Select Microsoft ODBC data source--->insert username & password --->Test Connection ---->Succeeded` , When i try to change the data source  through `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` i can't find `Microsoft ODBC data source` !!! it's so weird .

Comment: Please see **EDIT 5**.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the CSDK installation was successful, I suspect the **64-bit version** of the ODBC Administrator tool is running, while 32-bit IBM drivers were installed.  *32-bit drivers will only be visible running the 32-bit version of the ODBC Administrator tool.*  Microsoft ships both 32- and 64-bit versions in their OS, but the 64-bit version is the one launched from the menus.  (See this related question on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/419832).
You can run the 32-bit version from a command prompt:
          `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`
When you go to add your DSN, you should see the IBM drivers, like in the XP screenshot you posted.
Also, make sure you either enter the full path or `cd` to the `%windir%\SysWOW64` directory.  Otherwise, you be launching the 64-bit version, which incidentally is also called `odbcad32.exe`.

**EDIT**

Visual Studio 2012 is only available as a 32-bit application.  32-bit applications won't see any data sources created with the default 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool.
Two important caveats …

1. Make sure you are running the 32-bit ODBC Admin tool.  If you simply type `odbcad32.exe` from a command prompt, you will be running the **64-bit** version of the tool.  Be sure to launch it using the full path: `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.
2. If your data source is a *system DSN*, try creating it as a *user DSN*. There appears to be a problem for users seeing the system DSNs in the server explorer in [VS 2012](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/729631/odbc-system-dsns-are-not-available-in-the-odbc-connection-manager) and [VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422385/unable-to-select-a-system-dsn-when-adding-a-data-connection-to-server-explorer).

**EDIT 2**

I've looked back through this and think there is still some missing requirement in your environment.  The are quite a few client packages from IBM and you may very well need one of the packages that is more comprehensive than the "IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio".

I would download and install the "**IBM Data Server Client**" found at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217.  Per IBM's description …

> This is the all in one client package and includes all the client
>   tools and libraries available. It includes add-ins for Visual Studio.

I was able to download the IBM Data Server Client.  Specifically, this is the one I chose.

> IBM Data Server Client (Windows AMD 64)
>   ibm_data_server_client_winx64_V10.5.zip  (576 MB)

Since this package was released on 2012-04-30, I would recommend applying the latest fix packs: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878

I don't think you want the IBM Informix .NET provider.  See "Table 1" in this [IBM tech article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/).  The article also walks through connecting to Informix and using the Visual Studio Add-In.

Comment: Thanks , i have done what you recommend but still can't see that dialog window in visual studio 2012 !!

Comment: Is your Visual Studio 64-bit?

Comment: Have you tried a newer verion of the CSDK?  The 4.10 version is compatible with your 12.10 version of IDS.  (See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.relnotes.doc/notes/csdk_410xc2/csdk_win_relnotes.html).  There are both 64 and 32 bit versions available.

Comment: How could i know if the V.S 64 bit or not ? My windows is 64-bit

Comment: Just figured out Visual Studio 2012 is 32-bit only.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603854/visual-studio-2012-64-bit.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could you look to my question with the new edit please?

Comment: Were you ever able to download the "IBM Database Add-ins for Visual Studio"?

Comment: No, I want direct link to this add-ins

Comment: I just downloaded the Add-ins plugin and didn't have any issue getting past the "I Confirm" button.  I would give it a try again.

Comment: I make `EDIT2`, could you look to the question please.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Visual Studio integration and Entity Framework support is only by using IBM DS driver (IBM Data Server Client) which uses DRDA protocol.
The drivers included with Informix Client SDK uses native protocol called SQLI.
You may try after installing IBM DS Driver. 
Unfortunately the IBM DS Driver has limited functionality with Informix server.